# Does "simplification" relation reflect "traditionalization" relation in Unihan?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters

It is said many words here http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/#SCTC about kSimplifiedVariant and kTraditionalVariant field cases (5 cases). But I didn't understand, if these two relations reflect each other? For example if A is simplified version of B, then does it mean that B is traditional version of A?

Answer (score 5):

Let me summarize the cases and try to answer your question (TC = Traditional Chinese character set, SC = Simplified Chinese character set).

1. Some characters *were never simplified*. For example, `井 U+4E95` is in TC and in SC (and for that matter, most characters). In the Unihan database, codepoints like these have *neither* a **kSimplifiedVariant** *nor* a **kTranditionalVariant** (both fields are empty).
2. There is a traditional version of the character, only present in TC. For example, `書 U+66F8` is in TC (and not in SC).  The **kSimplifiedVariant** of `書` is `书`.
3. The is a simplified version of the character, only present in SC. For example, `书 U+4E66` is in SC (and not in TC). The **kTraditionalVariant** of `书` is `書`.
4. The character is used in both character sets depending on context. This is a bit of a mess, and I've written [more about it here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/3225/788)

#### The relations should "reflect each other", but they're not a bijection

It *should* be the case that if *X.kTraditionalVariant includes Y*, then *Y.kSimplifiedVariant includes X*. When I last checked the data about a year ago, there was at least one bug where that wasn't the case.

This does **not** mean that the relation is one-to-one *or* onto. There are some cases that are truly bizarre; [check this out here for all of the weird cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguities_in_Chinese_character_simplification)

Comment: As an example from the weird cases page, SC "干" corresponds to four (!) TC characters: "乾干幹榦", with different meanings and different pronunciations. This sometimes creates comical results when SC users translate things via Google, such as translating "干货" into "fuck goods".